# Name of the paper that suffered a famous editor mistake

Tags: experimental-physics, publishing

I have heard about a "famous" mistake made on a physics paper by the editor of a scientific journal but I can't seem to find the paper or even to recall what it was about. Has anyone hear of this and would know the paper in question?

The part of the story I remember is the following : It was at a time when personal computers weren't a thing and editorial work was a manual job. The editor erased a point from an experimental plot thinking it was a smudge while it was in fact the central discovery of the article.